# Get a process number with MPI_Allreduce

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

I am using `MPI_Allreduce` with MPI_MAX to get a maximum value computed by a number of processes:

```
MPI_Allreduce(&Max_Proc,&MaxGrid,1,double,MPI_MAX,COM);
```

How can I know the number/rank of the process that contains the maximum value `Max_Grid` ?

Comment: You might want to read up on the MPI_MAXLOC operator, which will provide for you the MAX value and location (rank) of the process the value came from.

http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-1.1/mpi-11-html/node79.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, it has the anwser i was looking for. I had some trouble applying your second example though